# Redis - Bind interfaces does not work (Connection refused)!

Tags: redis

I'm trying to configure Redis (`redis.conf`, `bind` parameter) to accept access only from certain ips. In my case I want to enable access for the loopback network interface (`127.0.0.1`/`::1`) and for the ip `192.168.56.101` (`192.168.56.102` is the ip of the Redis server). According to all the documentation that I have read so far the configuration below should work...

```
bind 127.0.0.1 ::1 192.168.56.101
```

... but that's not what happens.

I've tried several other configurations...

```
bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.56.101 ::1
bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.56.101
bind 192.168.56.101
bind 192.168.56.0
bind 192.168.0.0
```

... and nothing works. =|

The only configuration that worked was this...

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

But, this configuration opens access to any ip!

**NOTE:** The `protected-mode` parameter (`redis.conf`) has a `no` value.

**Any idea what might be happening?**

**REFERENCE:**

> [Redis bind to more than one IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16120287/redis-bind-to-more-than-one-ip)
>
> https://redis.io/topics/security
>
> http://download.redis.io/redis-stable/redis.conf

**FURTHER QUESTION:**

How could I enable access for an IP range (`bind` parameter)? Something like...

```
bind 192.168.56.0
```

... or...

```
bind 192.168.56.0/24
```

In these examples any machine with an ip starting at "192.168.56" will have access to the Redis server.

@Carl Dacosta
@Jacky

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the `bind` configuration and `IP-whitelist`.

The `bind` configuration specifies the IP addresses that Redis listens to. If you bind Redis to loopback interface, only local clients can access Redis. If you want other hosts to access Redis, you have to bind Redis to all network interfaces (i.e. 0.0.0.0), or some specified network interfaces.

What's you need is `IP-whitelist`, which lists the IP addresses that can access Redis. AFAIK, so far, Redis **DOES NOT** support that (correct me, if I'm wrong).

There are other solutions to limit the access to Redis (all these solution needs Redis **NOT** to bind on loopback interface).

> Limit access by authentication

You can use the `requirepass` configuration to set a password for Redis. Only clients with the password can access Redis.

> Limit access by OS utility

On Linux, you can use `iptables` to control the network access. With this utility, you can only allow specified hosts to access the port that Redis bind to.